# How to remove a comment using a c program

Tags: c, comments

I am just learning C and I am trying to read and write to an existing file. My task is to remove any comments from a the existing file that start with a "%" for instance:

1. this is an example
2. This is also an example
3. %example continued
4. % continuing
5. Eaxmple123456 % example

As shown in the example above I would remove lines 3 and 4 and everything to the right including the % in line 5. I would however write line 1, 2, and the first half of 5 to the existing file.

What I am trying to do is the read the file until it hits "%" from there it will skip to the next line, this process will continue until EOF. Here is my code thus far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    FILE *fpointer1,*fpointer2;
    int letter;
    char *mode1 = "r";
    char *mode2 = "w";
    fpointer1 = fopen("example_file.m",mode1);
    fpointer2 = fopen("example_file2.m",mode2);


                     while(letter != EOF){ //opens while                                        

                              if(letter!='%')
                             fputc(letter,fpointer2);


                                   else { //opens else


                                           while(letter!='\n'&&letter!='%'){ // opens 2nd while
                                               letter=fgetc(fpointer1);

                } // closes second while
            } // closes else
    }, // closes while

    fclose(fpointer1);
    fclose(fpointer2);

    return 0;
} // end program
```

Comment: You need to post some code you've tried along with a specific issue you need help with.

Comment: Sorry about that I just uploaded my code. @Joe

Comment: So what goes wrong?

Comment: 1) `fpointer1 = fopen("example_file.m",mode1);
    fpointer2 = fopen("example_file.m",mode2);` : Use temporary files or read all of them once and output them. 2) `fpointer1++;` : just bad.

Comment: @Joe I am currently using a windows OS and using GCC to compile however when I compile my code I keep getting  "warning: passing argument 1 of puts makes pointer from integer without a cast. Too many arguments to function 'puts' "

Comment: 3) `puts(letter,fpointer2);` : Use `fputc` instead of `puts`.

Comment: When you open a file in `"w"` mode, the contents of the file will be lost.

Comment: `fpointer1++;` -- This doesn't do what you think it does. Don't use pointer arithmetic on pointers that are handles such as filepointers. The internal position marker of the file will advance by calling `fgetc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ah ok. So then if I decided to use temp files then I should be fine if I use the "w" mode correct?

Comment: @MOehm how would I accomplish that?

Comment: You have already accomplished it. Just throw out the `fpointer++`.

Comment: 4) To compare with `EOF` the type of `letter` must be `int`.

Comment: 5) `letter=getc(fpointer1)!='%'` --> `(letter=getc(fpointer1))!='%'`, `},` --> `}`

Comment: 6) `while((letter=getc(fpointer1))!='%' && letter != EOF){` : If `%` is found, the loop ends there.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I thought it would have continued because of the "&& letter !=EOF" so it will still end why is that?

Comment: A && B (A : false ) ==> false.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so then should I use || instead of &&?

Comment: I think that the condition of the outer loop should be EOF only.

Comment: Ok, so then I should change type "letter" to a int instead of a char then my while loop will only be while(letter!=EOF);

Comment: If anyone is still willing to help me it appears my program has entered an unlimited loop and I can't figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Sample code](https://ideone.com/K9lPtV) for basic processing

Answer (score 0):

It will be very helpful adding a state variable as 'incomment' as seen in this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    FILE *fpointer1,*fpointer2;
    int letter, incomment = 0;
    char *mode1 = "r";
    char *mode2 = "w";
    fpointer1 = fopen("example_file.m",mode1);
    fpointer2 = fopen("example_file2.m",mode2);


    while ((letter=fgetc(fpointer1)) != EOF) { //opens while

        if(letter=='%') {
            incomment = 1;
        }
        else if(letter=='\n') {
            incomment = 0;
        }

        if(!incomment) {
            fputc(letter,fpointer2);
        }
    } // closes while

    fclose(fpointer1);
    fclose(fpointer2);

    return 0;
} // end program
```